# distance between a point and boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In the usual topology, let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open set and $C \subseteq A$ a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\forall x \in C$,  $d(x, \operatorname{Fr}(A)) > 0$. I have to prove that the distance between $x$ and the boundary of $A$ is positive. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What exactly is meant by $\mathrm{Fr}(A)$? That could be used to denote $\overline A\cap\overline{A^c}$ or $\overline A\setminus A$.

Comment: We use the notation Fr(A) for boundary of A. Fr(A) means frontera in spanish.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I ask is that $\mathrm{Fr}$ can also be an abbreviation for the English word "frontier," which is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \in C$, we know that $x \in A$ which is open. So there is some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq A$. All points in $B(x,r)$ are not in $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ (as they are interior points of $A$), so $d(x,\operatorname{Fr}(A)) \ge r > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A is open so every point in A, especially points of C have an open neighbourhood of radius rx  contained A, so the distance to the boundary is larger than or equal to rx.

Using the compactness of C we now can select a finite subcover and find a positive distance fro C to boundary of A.